# Is "10 liters of gas is charged in/to the tank" correct?

Tags: verbs

> The tank is charged with 10 liters of gas.

I am trying to rewrite the sentence above such that gas is the subject. My example is as follows:

> - 10 liters of gas is charged in/to the tank.
> - The amount of gas charged in/to the tank is 10 liters.

Could anyone advise me on whether the usage "charged in/to" is correct?

Comment: What type of 'tank' are you referring to.  A car's gas tank?  A propane tank?  Sherman tank?  Different tanks may use different verbs.

Comment: The original sentence, "The tank is charged with...", sounds sounds kind of non-fluent to this US English speaker; *charged* only seems to be used in technical writing.  In everyday speech we would normally say the tank is *filled* with gas.

Comment: I think "gas (or other material such as water) is filled in the tank" is grammatically incorrect.  I want to know whether  "gas is charged in the tank" is grammatically correct or incorrect.

Comment: You need to specify what the gas (gas or liquid such as gasoline) is and what the tank (container) is. For example, when you add freon to a refrigeration system, you *charge* the system. I imagine the difference might be volume vs. pressure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Charged" is used for electrical storage, like batteries.  A gasoline (or *petrol*, in BrE) tank would be "filled".

> I **filled** the gas tank with fifteen gallons.
>
> I **charged** my cell phone overnight so now it's at 100 percent.

Similarly, you will *fill* (or *fill up*) any other container:

> We **filled** our **water bottles** before we went on the long hike.
>
> They **filled up** their **suitcases** with souvenirs from the countries they visited.

As with almost anything in English, this can be metaphorical:

> The bad English teacher **filled** his students' **heads** with antiquated grammar rules.